# How to fire a script that is created after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, webforms

So I am implementing a javascript implementation for cart abandonment. One script I run is for the shopping cart, but the problem is I am using asp.net webforms. If I use an asp literal, the script does not fire. The text simply is altered for that property, but it does not fire.

What should I be using instead of a asp literal to when i alter its text it immediately fires.

**Update:**

The problem I have having is triggering the java script to run once it is in the literal control. How do I go about that?

The issue is that scripts load with the document and since this script is created due to some user event after that, I need to somehow run the code behind that literal.

**2nd Update:**
I guess I need to verify that the script text getting outputted to literal.text is actually in proper format first, then delve deeper if that isn't the root cause of my problem.

Here is what creates the script...Listrakawesome is the asp literal:

```
StringBuilder coollistrak = new StringBuilder();
            coollistrak.AppendLine("<script>(function(d) {if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('ltkAsyncListener', d);else{e=document.documentElement; e.ltkAsyncProperty = 0; e.attachEvent('onpropertychange',function(e){if(e.propertyName=='ltkAsyncProperty'){d();}});}})(function(){/********** Begin Custom Code **********/");
            foreach (CartItem ci in cart.CartItems)
            {
                string relPath = ci.ProductPicURL.Substring(ci.ProductPicURL.IndexOf("//") + 2);
                relPath = relPath.Substring(relPath.IndexOf("//") + 1);
                coollistrak.AppendLine("_ltk.SCA.AddItemWithLinks('" + ci.SKU + "', " + ci.Quantity + ", '" + Math.Round(ci.Price, 2).ToString() + "', '" + ci.VariantName + "', '" + relPath + "','" + SE.MakeProductVariantLink(ci.VariantID, SE.GetVariantSEName(ci.VariantID)) + "');");
            }
            coollistrak.AppendLine("_ltk.SCA.Submit();/********** End Custom Code **********/});</script>");

            Listrakawesome.Text = coollistrak.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Here is what is outputted to the literal.text:

```
"<script>(function(d) {if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('ltkAsyncListener', d);else{e=document.documentElement; e.ltkAsyncProperty = 0; e.attachEvent('onpropertychange',function(e){if(e.propertyName=='ltkAsyncProperty'){d();}});}})(function(){/********** Begin Custom Code **********/_ltk.SCA.AddItemWithLinks('sku', qty, 'price', 'productname', 'imglink','pagelink');_ltk.SCA.Submit();/********** End Custom Code **********/});</script>"
```

*Question:* Speaking generally, Whenever I change the literal.text that contains a script, should that script function and fire when that occurs or is an additional step necessary?

Comment: When are you changing the literal text?

Comment: @Kramb Yes I am. So when I appendline for javasript it looks great in my stringbuilder, but the next step of setting literal.text = stringbuilder.tostring(); produces a messy output with "/r/n" throughout. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding the "/r/n" into the string yourself?

Comment: @Kramb No I am not. I am combining individual appendline statements together and that seems to solve most of them, but I still will have other appendline statements that are needed and affected by this.

Comment: Just realized my answer didn't answer the original question, so the literal control answer will be here.
<asp:Literal Id="lit_description" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>

Comment: @Kramb even after switching to passthrough mode it happens!

Comment: literal.text = stringbuilder.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />");

Comment: @Kramb That works for that portion. See above update for more info.

Comment: Post the script you are using, may be easier to fix once we see the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

My problem essentially was that I didn't place this within the context of the pageload event. Doing so solved what I wanted to accomplish, but does not solve the original problem.  Ultimately to solve that problem I would have needed to rearrange how that function was being accessed in the c# file.

The pageload solution works just fine for my purposes however.